# Exchange Server 2003: Auto-BCC

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003

We are Windows Server 2003 SBS and only recently we started using the bundled Exchange Server 2003.

Being unfamiliar, I can't seem to make it auto-bcc (like in qmail), I've tried using the "Rules" of each user account, but the "Sender" field is not what I want.

Let me outline in detail

Original Email: peter@abc.com -> mark@mycompany.com

Using rules for auto forward to "john@mycompany.com": The sender is shown as "mark@mycompany.com" and not as "peter@abc.com".

Using QMAIL's auto-bcc, it showed as "peter@abc.com".

**Edit 1:**

The forwarding works now, thanks. Now I've got another problem.

My users have another request, they would like to mutual forward, say:

mark@mycompany.com -> william@mycompany.com

william@mycompany.com -> mark@mycompany.com

This would generate this error,  under some circumstances:

`A configuration error in the e-mail system caused the message to bounce between two servers or to be forwarded between two recipients.  Contact your administrator.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Active Directory Users and Computers open the properties for the Mark user account. On the Excgange General tab click the Delivery Properties button and add John as the forwarding address. From your posting you probably want to tick the box "Deliver messages to both forwarding address and mailbox".

If you want to forward to more than one person you create a distribution group and put the group in as the forwarding address.

This will preserve the original sender's address.

JR

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Another question, how do I create the distribution group?

Comment: In AD Users and Computers select the Organisational Unit where you want to create the distribution group. Right click the OU and choose New then Group. Set the group type to "Distribution". I usually leave the Group scope on Global (the difference between Global and Universal is a bit involved to explain). Feed in the group name as appropriate. Note that it may take a few minutes for Exchange to ste up the group's e-mail address.

Comment: Thanks, works now. But now got another problem, please see above.

Comment: Create a distribution group containing both Mark and William and set this group as the forwarding address for both users. Leave the "Deliver messages to both ..." box ticked for both users. Now any mail that comes in for either Mark or William is delivered to them both without any mail loops.